# How to create custom jquery trigger based on existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email-validation, parsley.js

I have a sign up form with **email**,
I'm using ParsleyJS to validate the client side.

When i'm using the `data-parsley-trigger="keyup"`attribute, its working perfect, but
we want to filter the `keyup` only when the user press the `@` keyboard button,
because we prefer it to start the parsley validation not on the first keyup.

The parsley framwork support the jquery events so i adding my own custom keyup should work.

Something like:

```
<input type="text" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-trigger="focusout customkeyup"/>

jQuery('#myForm').keyup( function(e) {
    if (e.which == 50) {
        console.log('Charcter was typed. It was: " + String.fromCharCode(e.which)');
        jQuery(document).trigger('customkeyup');
    }
});
```

but it does not work - i want it to start validationg onle after the `@` was pressed, and unfortunately only the `focusout` seem to work, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved:

I manually stop the `keyup` trigger by using `stopPropagation()` and only when the `@` gets clicked, then manually trigger my custom trigger.

```
jQuery('#contactEmail').keyup( function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.which == 50) {
        console.log('Charcter was typed. It was: " + String.fromCharCode(e.which)');
        jQuery('#contactEmail').trigger('customkeyup')
    }
});
```

and the input:

```
<input type="text" id="contactEmail" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-trigger="customkeyup"/>
```